# Bar chart in details band renders with final record data for each record

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I'm making a basic SQL-based report with Jasper Reports.  I've created a bar chart in the detail band using data from the main dataset query.  When I preview it with multiple rows of data returned, I get one graph per record, as expected, but the bars on the chart all reflect the final record of data - even though other text fields with field expressions show the correct values, even within the chart title itself!

I've been looking through the jaspersoft PDF docs a fair bit and tried playing with different values for the chart's evalationTime and its dataset's incrementType and resetType, but none of it seems to help, and I'm pretty sure the defaults are correct ("Now", "None" and "Report" respectively).

It seems like a workaround might be to make a subreport, which I haven't figured out yet, but it doesn't seem like this should be necessary - any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

- [report jrxml](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/questions/prr2_0.jrxml)

Comment: Can you share your JRXML?

Comment: It's linked above as "report jrxml".